# Can I use shared gem in rails directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to use one gem installed in system directory at a Rails project.For a certain reason, I cannnot add it to Gemfile and bundle install.Basicaly, I use bundler.

I want to do like this,

```
require 'gem_installed_in_vendor/bundle'
require 'gem_installed_in_system'
```

I wonder removing `disable_shared_gems` option help my hope,and I delete it from `.bundle/config`.But,it doens't work hopely.

output of `bundle config` is,

```
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.

path
Set for your local app (/Users/my_name/works/thisApp/.bundle/config):   "vendor/bundle"
```

and `which gem`'s output is,

```
/Users/my_name/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

Comment: Sorry, I solve this problem by making *Gemfile.local*. http://qiita.com/vzvu3k6k/items/12aff810ea93c7c6f307